# What alternative is there to the recycle method in Java's HttpMethod?

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

We're using the [PostMethod](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/PostMethod.html) in org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods and noticed that the [recycle method](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpMethod.html#recycle%28%29) from the HttpMethod interface has been deprecated.

Is there an alternative to this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the idea is to simply create a new one.

The cost of creating new short lived objects is actually pretty cheap and a lot less error prone than attempting to maintain an object pool.